# I want to display field on Parameter Value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Parameter @Language in SSRS Report which have two value English=2 and French=1
I want to display different fields on parameter value like

> =IIF(Parameters!Language.Value=1,Fields!new_french.Value,Fields!new_english.Value)

but it shows error.

Comment: and what would that error be?, where are you using that expression?, a textbox, a tablix?

Comment: does it actually show 1 and 2 in the drop down of your parameter `@Language` ??

Comment: I am using it in text-box expression and it show "unknown collection member" red line under Fields!new_french.Value

Comment: so, do you actually have a dataset with a `new_french` column?

Comment: yes, new_french and new_english two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the First aggregate and scoping the field names to their dataset name.  For example, if the dataset name that contains the `new_french` and `new_english` columns is named `Languages` then the expression would be:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Language.Value=1, First(Fields!new_french.Value, "Languages"), First(Fields!new_english.Value, "Languages"))
```